# How to manage time in seconds in text format?

Tags: excel, vba, text, time

I’m reporting on one of the older telecom applications which exports the data in a text format.

I can convert the text to time.

Issue: The issue surfaces when I get a time in this format
-   :00,
-   :22,

The data is changing from :22 to 00:22:00 which changes 22 seconds to 22 minutes.

```
Sub FixTime()
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A10")
        cell.Value = "00" & cell.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

This does not happen if I have 00:22:00 (minutes) and 01:22:00 (Hour).

Comment: What's exactly the value from the system?  `:22` nothing in from of that? just a string

Comment: So long as it is a text string, just test to see what it is. eg: if it has a length of 3 and the first character is a colon, then prepend `00:00`.

Comment: If a cell contains `:22` this is a text and not a number. You cannot calculate with it.
If you turn that into a `00:22` then Excel assumes `hh:mm` (hours:minutes). If you wante it to be seconds you must enter `00:00:22`. • So you need to adjust your code so that it adds `00:00` infront of your `:22` to keep it seconds.

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept of text -> Time conversion in order to be able to calculate. The problem is that I have multiple times coming out of the system that are all in TEXT format. If I add 00:00 into the Macro then my :22 gets nicely fixed but everything else ends up in something completely ridiculous. :00:55 for example ends up with 00:00:00:55... :/

Comment: :22 represents 22 sec of a call length. Some calls are :02:35 - 2 minutes and 35 sec. The system spits out time in a text format making it very complicated to report on.

Comment: Is your seconds data "-: 25" or ": 25"?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO Maciej. I'm hoping that I used some valid examples and this code will get you started!

```
Sub FixTime()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("A1:A10")
        Select Case Len(cell.Value)
            Case 3 'seconds
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TimeSerial(0, 0, Right(cell.Value, 2))
            Case 6 'minutes
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TimeSerial(0, Mid(cell.Value, 2, 2), Right(cell.Value, 2))
            Case 8 'full time
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TimeSerial(Left(cell.Value, 2), Mid(cell.Value, 4, 2), Right(cell.Value, 2))
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

(the code has been adjusted using `TimeSerial` as per @Pᴇʜ's comment)

I'm converting values from column A and dropping the results into column B (feel free to skip the `Offset(0,1)` part to simply replace the existing values):

[image]

Comment: Thank You everyone for amazing help! Cheers!

Comment: No problem at all Maciej. Feel free to upvote and/or accept one of the answers if that helped. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.

Comment: @JustynaMK just a note, while this will work at first glance, it produces only a string (that might look like a time, but is again only text). I recommend to produce a real time format (that Excel can calculate with) and not letting Excel guess. It might guess wrong (especially with dates, and also on times as the original question shows). The most reliable approach is to use `TimeSerial` to produce a real time.

Comment: Very good point, thank you @Pᴇʜ ! I have adjusted the code accordingly.

Comment: @JustynaMK well, you again used `Format()`. Note that this will turn it into a string again! `Format()` can only return strings! just remove `Format` completely and set the `.NumberFormat` for that cells to time format of your choice. This way the cell contains a real time value (that is formatted by number format). Now Excel can use that and calculate with it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ removed :-) makes sense, thanks. I just personally didn't like the default format in which my Excel was displaying these times, e.g. `12:22:00 AM` instead of simply `00:22:00`.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to use the [TimeSerial function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timeserial-function) to produce a real time format and not a string again. The disadvantage of using the [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) is that is produces a string again. Note that this string might look like a time but **it is not**. For Excel it is just a string while if you use `TimeSerial()` you will get a real time that Excel recognizes as time and can calculate with.

**Rule No. 1 when you are working with dates and times is:**
Never let Excel convert date or times on it's own. Never let Excel guess which format this string is. Never let Excel decide anything! • Instead always be specific and parse the string yourself. You are the only one who can tell for 100 % sure which format should be the correct one. Excel will definitely fail soon or later.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertStringIntoTimes()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Range("A1:A10").Cells
        Dim RawData() As String 'split cell text by `:`
        RawData = Split(Cell.Text, ":")

        'validate if one is empty string or non-numeric
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To UBound(RawData)
            If RawData(i) = vbNullString Then
                RawData(i) = 0 'epmty string is considered to be zero
            ElseIf Not IsNumeric(RawData(i)) Then
                GoTo NextCell  'non-numeric cannot be handled continue with next cell
            End If
        Next i

        Dim OutputTime As Date
        Select Case UBound(RawData)
            Case 2: '01:22:33 or :22:33
                OutputTime = TimeSerial(RawData(0), RawData(1), RawData(2))

            Case 1: '22:33 or :33
                OutputTime = TimeSerial(0, RawData(0), RawData(1))

            Case 0: '33
                OutputTime = TimeSerial(0, 0, RawData(0))

            Case Else: 'anything else that connot be converted
                GoTo NextCell
        End Select

        'set numberformat and write value as real time
        Cell.NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM" 'choose your desired time format
        Cell.Value = OutputTime

NextCell:
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Left is the input data, right column is the output that the procedure will give.</sup>*

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this.

```
Sub FixTime()
    Dim t As Double
    Dim s As String
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A10")
        If Left(cell, 3) = "- :" Then
            s = Replace(cell, "- :", "")
            t = Val(s) / 24
            t = t / 3600
            cell.Value = Format(t, "hh:mm:ss")
        Else
            cell.Value = "00" & cell.Value
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Format` has one big disadvantage: It produces a string again. I highly recommend not to use strings when using dates or times. Only use `Format()` when this is shown on a report/printout, or label in a UserForm or something. Never output a date/time as a string if this is meant to be data. You will run into issues soon or later. Also never let Excel guess.